# search rows of loaded tableview using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, search

Here is the scenario - I have two separate view controllers named A and B.
ViewController A has tableview loaded with some data and ViewController B has a UISearch Bar.

When i type in uisearchbar it searchs for text in some array named arrAllData and result is stored in another array name arrFilterData.

Now i need search the content of arrFilterData in tableview of ViewController A  and highlight it and which is already loaded with data. How do i proceed with this.

Thanks,

Comment: Please write your code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

Reload your `ViewControllerA` tableView after searching finishes.

and in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method of tableView check for object at current indexPath in `arrAllData` belongs in `arrFilterData`.

if `YES` then Highlight cell, otherwise not.

Like,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


   if (Cell == nil) {

      acell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
   }

   if([arrFilterData containsObject:[arrAllData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){

      //Highlight Cell
   }
   else{
      //Do not highlight cell
   }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type any keyword in `searchbar`, then **textDidChange** method is called. Please perform below steps.

```
 (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText  
  {    
   NSPredicate *resultPredicate;  
   resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"strEpisodeName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];  
   arrFilterData = (NSMutableArray *)[arrAllData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];  
  }
```

Note: In above code, I have searched with entity variable **'strEpisodeName'**